# SAP .NET Connector, Connect to a Single RFC destination using multiple SAP user accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sap-dotnet-connector

I have a .Net application which use to create SAP sales orders through it. When I used a (common)single SAP user account to create the **rfcDestination** it works perfectly with multiple users.
But when I use user accounts of the logged in user it gives following exception.

```
RfcInvalidStateException:Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.Provider.SapException: destination MAQ is invalid ---> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: destination MAQ is invalid
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcFunction.Invoke(RfcDestination destination)
   at Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.Provider.SapConectionProvider.Invoke[T](IDataRequet request, String username, String password, IRfcFunction& rfcFunction)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.Provider.SapConectionProvider.Invoke[T](IDataRequet request, String username, String password, IRfcFunction& rfcFunction)
   at Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.SapDataRepository2.Invoke[T](IDataRequet request, String user, String password)
08:20:52.016 [23] ERROR General - ATP Check Exception:Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.Provider.SapException: destination MAQ is invalid ---> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidStateException: destination MAQ is invalid
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcFunction.Invoke(RfcDestination destination)
   at Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.Provider.SapConectionProvider.Invoke[T](IDataRequet request, String username, String password, IRfcFunction& rfcFunction)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.Provider.SapConectionProvider.Invoke[T](IDataRequet request, String username, String password, IRfcFunction& rfcFunction)
   at Portal.Infrastructure.Data.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.SAP.SapDataRepository2.Invoke[T](IDataRequet request, String user, String password)
```

And this only happened when multiple users calling a rfc at the same time.

Does SAP .Net connector supports for multiple SAP user accounts??

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use RfcCustomDestination for multiple logons:

web.config

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="SAP.Middleware.Connector">
      <sectionGroup name="ClientSettings">
        <section name="DestinationConfiguration" type="SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationConfiguration, sapnco"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


  <SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>
          <!-- multiple ways to do this ... -->
          <add NAME="DEV" SYSID="DEV" ASHOST="mysapashost.com" SYSNR="00" CLIENT="0000" LANG="EN" MAX_POOL_SIZE="5" IDLE_TIMEOUT="10" USER="anything it is not used" PASSWD="anything it is not used"/>

        </destinations>
      </DestinationConfiguration>
    </ClientSettings>
  </SAP.Middleware.Connector>


</configuration>
```

app code:

```
private static RfcCustomDestination mydestination()
{
    //"DEV" is the name of the destination in the web.config
    RfcDestination rfcDest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("DEV");

    RfcCustomDestination _customDestination = rfcDest.CreateCustomDestination();
    _customDestination.User = "LoggedOnSAPUserid";
    _customDestination.Password = "LoggedOnSAPPassword";

    return _customDestination;
}

public string runMyRFC(string myInput)
{
    RfcCustomDestination _customDestination = mydestination();
    IRfcFunction Results = _customDestination.Repository.CreateFunction("Z_SOME_RFC");

    Results.SetValue("RFCInput", myInput);

    Results.Invoke(_customDestination);

    string threResult;

    //. . .

    return theResult;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this but got same results with different SAP login s. So I use this RfcCustomDestination with my common SAP user and seems its working fine... Because I got the above exception with the common user with my previous approach too.